# JS copying rich text from IE/Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, clipboard, microsoft-edge

I have a button on my website, and the expectation is that when the button is clicked, a chunk of **rich text (in html format)** should be copied to user's clipboard, so they can then paste it to a rich text supported editor (i.e. outlook) with format.

I got it working in Chrome/FF by using multiple different approaches, such as using `clipboard.js` or `clipboard-polyfill.js`, or executing native copy command like below:

```
function copyToClip(str) {
      function listener(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", htmlstr);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
    };
```

However, **none of the above works in Microsoft Edge or IE**. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the goal in Edge/IE, and if so, how should I do it?

P.S. I want to avoid using ZeroClipboard.js as much as possible because it will require user to install/enable Flash.

Thank you

Comment: When i searched for "IE clipboard without flash", it came up with quite a few no-flash results.

Comment: @KevinB IE can easily copy plain text, but this question is for "rich text"

Comment: Can you prove there's a difference?

Comment: @KevinB Sure, for example this line doesn't work in IE: `e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", htmlstr);`, only plain text works like this: `e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);`

Comment: Basically... Without flash , you either have to use `execCommand('copy')`, or select the text and instruct the user to press CTRL+C for browsers that don't support `execCommand('copy')`.

Comment: @KevinB thanks! can you please share a `ctrl+c` example? maybe I can hide the html that I want to copy, and use selector to get it and call a `ctrl+c`

Comment: Maybe not an example, but, you'd use this api to set the selection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection and then use some form of tooltip or popup to instruct the user to press Ctrl+C

Answer (score 0):

This is working well with internet explorer

```
 function paste() {
            //internet explorer
            var value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
            document.getElementById("Text1").value = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Microsoft Edge Version 83.0.478.45 (Official build) (64-bit).I tried with this code and it worked for me.

```
function CopyToClipboard() {
    var controlValue = "Assign Your Data";
        var textare = document.createElement('textarea');
        textare.textContent = controlValue;
        textare.style.position = "fixed";
        document.body.appendChild(textare);
        textare.focus();
        textare.select();
        try {
            window.focus();
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(textare.textContent);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textare);
        }
 }
```